# $P^{100}$ order group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a group with $|G|=p^{100}$

- a) If there exists a unique subgroup of order $p^k$ for $1\leq k \leq 100$ then $G$ is cyclic.
- b) If there exists a subgroup of order $p^k$ for $1\leq k\leq 100$ then $G$ is cyclic.
- c) There exists a proper non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.
- d) If $G$ is non-abelian the $\text Aut(G)$ has a subgroup $H$ with $H\neq \{e\}$ and $H\neq G$.

  Here Option a and c are clear to me as they are direct from theories.So a and c are true. This problem has multiple option correct. Please provide some suggestion for option b and d. thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Cauchy's theorem.  You are guaranteed a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: @KajHansen it says $p^k$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was saying for *some* $1 \leq k \leq 100$, not *every* $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) might not be correct is clear by Sylow's theorem because there exists subgroups of order $p^{k}$ for all $1\leq K \leq 100$ but it might not be cyclic. For example say $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{99}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

(D) has a typo I think! it will be $H\neq \{\ e\}\ $ and $H\neq Aut(G)$. This option is correct. You can consider Inn(G) , the subgroup of Aut(G) consisting of the inner automorphisms. Use the following isomorphism : $G/Z(G) \cong Inn(G)$. Observe that $|Inn(G)|=p^k$ where $1<k<100$. $k<100$ is pretty clear. Now why is $k>1$? This is because if $k=1$, then |Inn(G)|=p which says $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic and hence G abelian a contradiction. Now clearly Inn(G) has a subgroup of order p by Cauchy's theorem. This has to be a proper subgroup if not Inn(G) itself.

Comment: what does it tell us? :P

Comment: Order of Z(G) can be $p,p^2,...,p^{98}$. From here, exactly how to conclude?

Comment: ok let's add some more..

Comment: so then the only remaining case is when $|Z(G)|=p^{n-1}$ but that also implies $G$ is abelian right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I edited exactly!!!